# Using central limit theorem (CLT) on random variables with known domain, but truncating the Normal(0,1) only on the possible values is more accurate?

Tags: normal-distribution, binomial-distribution, central-limit-theorem, truncated-normal-distribution

For instance, when we have a binomial random variable, we can approximately calculate its CDF using the central limit theorem, but I wonder if we can obtain a more accurate result if we condition the Normal random variable only on the possible values.
Let $S_n \sim \mathcal {Bi}(n,p)$, so we want to calculate $P(S_n \leq a)$ for $0 \leq a \leq n$.

Applying the CLT with no conditioning we obtain:
\begin{equation*}
    P(\mathcal{S}_n \leq a) = P(\frac{S_n-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}} \leq \frac{a-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}}) \approx P(Z \leq \frac{a-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}}) = unconditioned
\end{equation*}

In order to apply the CLT with conditioning, we calculate the possible values:

\begin{equation*}
    0 \leq \mathcal{S}_n \leq n 
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    -np \leq \mathcal{S}_n - np \leq n - np
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    \frac{-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}} \leq \frac{S_n-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}} \leq \frac{n(1-p)}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    -\sqrt{\frac{np}{1-p}} \leq Z \leq \sqrt{\frac{n(1-p)}{p}}
\end{equation*}

So Applying the CLT with conditioning we obtain:

\begin{equation*}
    P(\mathcal{S}_n \leq a) \approx P(Z \leq \frac{a-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}} \boldsymbol{|} -\sqrt{\frac{np}{1-p}} \leq Z \leq \sqrt{\frac{n(1-p)}{p}}) = conditioned
\end{equation*}

Is it true that the error with conditioned probability is always less than the unconditioned probability?

\begin{equation*}
    |P(S_n \leq a) - \textbf{conditioned}| \leq |P(S_n \leq a) - \textbf{unconditioned}|
\end{equation*}